# Check if my React array contains value if yes return certain component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I have to render different components based on:

- if the items contain a certain value
- and if all 10 items have that value

```
const MyComponent = ({ data }: Props) => {
  const filteredItems = data.items?.filter(
    (item) => item?.type.includes(MyType.Value1) || item?.type.includes(MyType.Value2)
  );

  filteredItems.map((item) => {
    if (item.type.includes(MyType.Value1)) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Component one />
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Component two />
      </div>
    );
  });
  return null;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

**1/ if the items contain a certain value**

```js
(data?.items || []).find(item => [your condition here]) && <ComponentToRenderIfTrue />
```

**2/ if all 10 items have that value**

```js
(data?.items || []).every(item => [your condition here]) && <ComponentToRenderIfTrue />
```

Comment: thanks, how should I bake that into my example?

Comment: Does this work in a retun as a jsx expression? for example
return(
{(item?.items || []).find(item => [contains('grid-cols')]) && 
            <GridCols  ItemType={TextBlockItem} scheme={scheme} gridCols={item?.[`grid-cols-three`]}/>
            }
)

Comment: Of course! No reason it would not work :)